# Use a secure tmpfile with saltstack

Tags: security, gnupg, salt-stack, temporary-files

I want to inject a gpg secret key with salt. The key itself is in a secure pillar, but to provide the key to the newly-installed gpg setup on the minion, I have to put the key into a file, so I have something like

```
import_gpg_key:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/secret.key
    - contents_pillar: gpg:secret_key
    - user: me
    - group: me
    - mode: 0600
  cmd.run:
    - name: gpg --batch --import /tmp/secret.key
    - runas: me
    - unless: gpg --list-secret-keys {{ pillar['gpg']['default_key_fingerprint'] }}

##  
# FIXME Is there no way to avoid
# writing the secret to disk, or
# at least use a secure tmpfile?
/tmp/secret.key:
  file.absent
```

As I said in my comment, I'd rather not write the secret to disk at all, but if that's unavoidable, is there some way to use a secure tmpfile with a randomized path that isn't easily guessable?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [module that allows gpg imports from text](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.gpg.html#salt.modules.gpg.import_key) you might call it using the [module state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html)

Untested sketch:

```
import_gpg_key:
  module.run:
    - name: gpg.import_key
    - user: me
    - kwargs:
        text: {{ pillar['gpg']['secret_key'] }}
    - unless: gpg --list-secret-keys {{ pillar['gpg']['default_key_fingerprint'] }}
```

I'm afraid that `unless` does not work here (at least it is not mentioned in the docs)- but you might use another `cmd.run` together with `watch_in` which might work as a condition for this state.